Decode a hex string
I have the following binary data what was saved as a hex
hex_str = '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'

I want to decode the above. Based on this answer I use the following
decoded = bytes.fromhex(hex_str).decode('utf-8')

This results in the following error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position
3: invalid start byte

Next, I try the following
decoded = bytes.fromhex(hex_str).decode('ascii')

This results in another error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position
0: ordinal not in range(128)

Please show me how to decode the hex.

That is not a hex string, but base64 encoding.
